# cefsharp shut down using bye timer in form

Tags: c#, cefsharp

hi i use cefsharp in winform after calling Cef.Shutdown(); in FormClosing and FormClosed this error show me :

[image]

but when using the button for close cefsharp problem solve!

how can shutdown cef by the timer?

Comment: you have to invoke the call of cef.shutdown if invokeisrequired.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: thanks for helping plz show me by example i use invoke but not work

Comment: Here is an working example: https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/WinFormsHTMLChromium/ As I understand Cefsharp you dont need to call Cef.Shutdown() in newer versions. But when you want to call it you need Cef.Initialize in the same UI Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dispatcher to call the Cef.Shutdown() method from the original thread of your application on assumption that you have not tried to call the method from another created thread.

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((Action)CefShutdown);
    Close();
}

private void CefShutdown()
{
    Cef.Shutdown();
    Close();
}
```

You may need to avoid calling `Application.Exit()` method before calling the `Cef.Shutdown()` method. This is because `Application.Exit()` method will dispose the object once called and hence no access. So, also avoid calling the `Application.Exit()` method before calling `Cef.Shutdown()`.

Thank you

Comment: thanks for answer. i use this code and calling Application.Exit() but hangup and not work